# How to make a page loop script

Tags: javascript, python, json, svg

Is there someone that can make this script download multiple pages, instead of one single page?

This is a script in Python:

```
import json, urllib

page_data = urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example/html5system/request/example-8/get/1/").read()
js = json.loads(page_data)
#print js['page']

with open('page1.svg', 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(js['page'].encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Do you want them to be downloaded into one big file, or into multiple files? I don't think the latter is possible.

Comment: multiple files or a single pdf

Comment: /get/page_number/ i need page 1 to 300

Comment: And write them into `page1.svg`, `page2.svg`, and so on?

Comment: Just put all the above code into a `for` loop that iterates from 1 to 300, and concatenates the number into the URL and output file.

Comment: i don`t know how to do it can you make the code

Comment: Come on, this is beginner stuff. It's just a `for` loop and string concatenation. I'm not regular Python programmer, I'd have to look up the exact syntax.

Comment: i have done python for 2 days, can almost nothing

Comment: Seems like this would be a good way to learn, but researching how to write loops. Having someone do it for you is not a good way to learn.

Comment: tried this one but didn`t work:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json, urllib

for i in range(1,301): # loop from 1 to 300
    page_data = urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example/html5system/request/example-8/get/%d/" % i).read()
    js = json.loads(page_data)

    with open('page%d.svg' % i, 'wb') as f_out: # save each page in a separate svg
        f_out.write(js['page'].encode('utf-8'))
        f_out.close()
```

I just added a simple loop around your existing code which runs for the numbers 1 to 300. I then did a string replacement `'%d' % i` which inserts the value of `i` where the `%d` is located in the string. I also did the same thing for the file name, so each page is saved to a separate .svg file.